# I am unable to use cellClick in dash_tabulator

Tags: javascript, python, plotly-dash, tabulator

I want to use **cellClick** to get the column details in a dash_tabulator.
But it is showing me none when I am using cellClick in another callback.

Here is my table code,

```
table = dash_tabulator.DashTabulator(
                id=table_id,
                data=data_records,
                columns=table_columns,
                downloadButtonType= download,
                # clearFilterButtonType={"css": "btn btn-outline-dark", "text": "Clear Filters"},
                options={
                    # "groupBy": "Type",
                    "layout": "fitColumns",
                    "printAsHtml": True,
                    "printStyled": True,
                    "dataTree": True,
                    "dataTreeStartExpanded": True,
                    "dataTreeChildIndent": 15,
                    'selectable': selectable,
                    'autoResize': True,
                    # 'maxHeight': "auto",
                    'maxWidth': 300,
                    'clipboard': True,
                    'rowFormatter':tabulator_ns('treeFormatter'),
                    'cellClick':tabulator_ns('cellClick'),
                    "headerVisible": True,
                    "printConfig":{"formatCells":True},

                }
```

I am also using javascript callbacks for **cellClick**, code as shown here.

```
cellClick:function(e, cell){
            alert("cellClick"+ cell.getColumn().getDefinition().field+ cell.getColumn().getDefinition().title);
            // // alert(cell.getValue())
            // // console.log("cellClick"+ cell.getColumn().getDefinition());
            var data = {'field': cell.getColumn().getDefinition().field, 
            'title': cell.getColumn().getDefinition().title}
            // // alert(data)
            // table.props.setProps({cellClick: 'field'})
            
            // cell.props.setProps({cellClick: 'field'}) 
            // alert(cell._cell.data)
            return data

        }
```

And here is new callback where I am using this cellClick property.

```
@app.callback(
    [
        Output('pl-modal', 'is_open')
    ],
    [
        Input('pl-table', 'rowClicked'),
        Input('pl-table', 'cellClick'),

    ],
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def show_pl_modal(selected_row, selected_cell ):
    print("rowselected", selected_row)
    print("cellselected", selected_cell)
```

I am getting required data in javascript alert but getting none for **cellselected** in new callback.

Comment: were you ever able to figure this out, i too am getting the exact same issue.

Comment: It wasn't implemented.